# How do I run the following query in Pymongo?

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm very new to pymongo, mongodb and python. I can get this query to run on mongodb but i can't get it to run on python?

```
db.crime.group({
    "key": {
        "Primary Type": true,
        "Arrest": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "Total": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.Total += true.length;
        else prev.Total++;
    }
});
```

Comment: cursor = db.crime.group({
    "key": {
        "Primary_Type": true,
        "Arrest": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "Total": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {if (true != null) if (true "instanceof Array") prev.Total += true.length; else prev.Total++;
    }
})

Comment: The reduce function in your question is incorrect.  What are you trying to do here with the crime collection?

Comment: I'm trying to group by Primary Type, Arrest and count the total ID's

Comment: Are you counting the total IDs per group?

Answer (score 0):

Looking to count IDs in each group by a composite key of 'Primary Type' and 'Arrest', you can implement this in `python` using `pymongo` in this manner:

```
key = {
    'Primary Type': '$Primary Type',
    'Arrest': '$Arrest'
}

pipeline = [{
    '$group': {
        '_id': key,
        'count': { '$sum': 1}
    }
}]

db.crime.aggregate(pipeline)
```

**Note that** from mongo 3.4 up, group query is deprecated so using aggregate is future proof in versions up to mongo 3.6 as shown above.

Comment: Thanks. i'll try this!